# Xampp on linux mint

Tags: linux, xampp

im trying to install xampp on "new" linux mint machine.

However im quite a noob to linux since i havnt used it for that long.

When i try to run the file that ive download from the following page:

[Xampp download](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html)

i get the following error two errors:

```
Could not display "/home/marc/Downloads/xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-0-installer.run".
```

and if i click yes

```
    Installing mime type handlers isn't supported

To search and install software which can open certain file types you have to install app-install-data.
```

can anyone tell me what the problem is and how i might fix it?

Comment: Linux Mint includes all the components of xampp in its standard packages. Why would you need xampp when you can just install Apache, PHP, MySQL and the rest from the standard OS installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to execute the file (e.g. open a terminal, navigate to your Downloads folder and run `bash xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-0-installer.run` (possibly it might need to be run otherwise, but thats my best guess)).

alternatively you might be presented to run/execute the file (instead of displaying it). if so, choose this option.

on the other hand, you might consider installing apache/php/mysql via your package manager.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is that you can use the chmod +x /your folder location/.run file that you want to install 
after that you can run following command 
./and your .run file name 
 example:-
in my case :- User@user~$su root
              it will ask for password so give it
              User@user~chmod +x /Downloads/xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-0-installer.run
              User@user~./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-0-installer.run